# Why is "activity" linked to "getActivity()" in Fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I'm reading the sunflower code which is offered to show how to use Kotlin in Android development: https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/HomeViewPagerFragment.kt

at line 50:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
```

but I can't find where the "activity" be defined. If "ctrl+click" in Android Studio, it jump to "getActivity()" in Fragment.java. If anyone can tell me where it be defined and what's the magic it jump to "getActivity()"?

It seems to be a var in AppCompatActivity or Fragment or any super class, but I don't know how to locate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Kotlin thing, not an Android SDK thing.

Quoting [the Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters):

> Methods that follow the Java conventions for getters and setters (no-argument methods with names starting with get and single-argument methods with names starting with set) are represented as properties in Kotlin.

In this case, we only have `getActivity()`, not `setActivity()`, so Kotlin treats it syntactically as a `val`.